# Adding point features by machine learning in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, digitizing, machine-learning

I've got several georeferenced traditional maps and there are circles on it. (these are the studied points) So I want to add point features to the middle of the circles. I could do it manually, but I wonder 'bout that’s possible by machine learning and if it does how.

Comment: Are the maps in color and do these circles have a distinct color which differ from other map elements?

Comment: The circles have distinct color and map elements differ from them.

Comment: Then you could try and and go with https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781784391645/1/ch01lvl1sec7/loading-rasters-using-raster2pgsql